# Click event not working inside colorbox

Tags: jquery

there is a link on my website. When I click on it a colorbox opens with some content.

There is a link in the colorbox's content and I want to add a click event on that link but its not working.

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
alert('a');
});
```

Comment: Could you add an example of not working part to hsfiddle, leave a refer to website or provide an html?

Comment: your link to your website doesn't work ( isn't a link )

Comment: Are you sure the anchor tag has the class link? If so, probably `$(document).on('click', '.link', alert)` should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery only works with elements that are loaded. make sure that you are setting up this code **after** the colorbox is loaded. you can do that by wrapping it in a 
`$(doument).ready(function(){});` on the colorbox html page

```
$(doument).ready(function(){
    $('.link').on('click', function() {
           alert('a');
     });
});
```